# Regular expression seems to treat one string as multiple substrings

Tags: javascript, regex

Why the following code returns "ZZZCamelCase"?? Doesn't such regex examine if the string starts and ends with small case a-z? As what I understand, the `str` variable should match such condition, so the console output should be "ZZZZZZZZZZZZ", but obviously it somehow breaks the `str`, and examine the substring against the regex. Why? and how can I tell the program to treat "testCamelCase" as one string?

```
var str = "testCamelCase"; 
console.log(str.replace(/^[a-z]+/, 'Z')); // ZZZCamelCase
```

Comment: @fuyushimoya Also to mention, no `i` flag

Comment: "Doesn't such regex examine if the string starts and ends with small case a-z?" No.

Comment: It is not clear to me what duplicate it is. The number of `Z` in the expected result was different in the beginning. Now, the regex just needs to match any Latin letter. If it is, this post must be closed.

Comment: You just need to read about quantifiers and global matching with [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp). It is basic regex knowledge.

Comment: my actual doubt is: if `^[a-z]+` means to match anything starts and ends with a-z, then why "testCamelCase" didn't pass the test? It seems this regex doesn't only check the beginning and end letter, but also the letters in between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are matching one or more *lower case* letters. That's going to be 'test' in your string, because after that comes an *uppercase* 'C'. So only 'test' gets rpelaced by 'ZZZ'

```
console.log(str.replace(/^[a-z]+/, 'ZZZ')); // ZZZCamelCase
```

Use

```
str.replace(/[a-z]/ig, 'Z')
```

to get 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZ'

Answer (score 2):

You are forgetting, that regex is case sensitive. This means, that `[a-z]` doesn't capture the whole string. `[a-zA-Z]` does. So does `[\w]` including digits from 0-9.